# Strange usage of static_cast

Tags: c++, null, zero, static-cast

I came over the following code construct in our production environment (heavily simplified however).

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct 
{
    char entry[10]; 
}
inn_struct;

typedef struct 
{    
    inn_struct directory;
} 
out_struct;


struct test
{
    static const int 
       ENTRY_LENGTH = (sizeof((static_cast<out_struct*>(0))->directory.entry) 
           / sizeof((static_cast<out_struct*>(0))->directory.entry[0]));
};

int main()
{
    test a;
    std::cout << test::ENTRY_LENGTH;
}
```

Now not considering the obviously obfuscated nature of it since it's just the old C way of determining the length of an array ... I am really bothered by the `static_cast` of the `0` value. ... Is this code acceptable? Can you please attach some passages from the c++ standard to your response which tells me (if) why this code is ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this code is perfectly acceptable. See §5.3.3/1 (emphasis mine).

> The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression, which is an **unevaluated** operand (Clause 5), or a paranthesized *type-id*.

The expression is not evaluated, so there's no problem with what looks like dereferencing a null pointer.

Note also that in C++11, you don't need to jump through that hoop, and can just directly reference the class member with sizeof, thanks to §5/8 (emphasis mine):

> In some contexts, *unevaluated operands* appear (5.2.8, 5.3.3, 5.3.7, 7.1.6.2). An unevaluated operand is not evaluated. An unevaluated operand is considered a full-expression. [ *Note:* In an unevaluated operand, **a non-static class member may be named** (5.1) and naming of objects or functions does not, by itself, require that a definition be provided (3.2). — *end note* ]

and §5.1.1/13:

> An *id-expression* that denotes a non-static data member or non-static member function of a class can only be used:
>
> - ..
> - if that *id-expression* denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated context *[Example:*

```
    struct S {
      int m;
    };

    int i = sizeof(S::m); // OK
    int j = sizeof(S::m + 42); // OK
```

> *- end example]*

Comment: Two notes regarding the better form (X::entry): 1. It does work in Clang and GCC, but doesn't work in Visual C++ 2013. 2. A better quote for it is at the end of [5.1.1], where there's also an example.

Comment: @bogdan added that section too, didn't read that far the first time. Also formatting that was annoying :-/